# Line count in multi-line column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, modern-experience, multiline-text-field

I have a simple custom list with multiple line column.
I need to get count in each multi line column of the list item. (not word count)

As of now, I am exporting the list to excel and by using excel formula, getting the line count in each cell.

Is this possible in SharePoint list itself with a separate count column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can accomplish this with OOTB feature. By looking into excel formula, I was hoping to accomplish this with JSON column formatting. However, the issue is **replace()** function replaces only the **first** occurrence of '\n'. You can repeat **replace()** function though if you know the expected max line count, but will not be reliable.

You may try using MS Flow/Power Automate to accomplish this.

Excel Formula:

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1
```

JSON Column Formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=indexOf([$Multiline] + '^', '^') - indexOf(replace([$Multiline], '\n', '') + '^', '^') + 1"

}
```

However, you can repeat **replace()** function to a known max number like below to accomplish your goal. But the result count might not be accurate if the actual line number is > then the number of times **replace()** used in the JSON.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=indexOf([$Multiline] + '^', '^') - indexOf(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace([$Multiline], '\n', ''), '\n', ''), '\n', ''), '\n', ''), '\n',''), '\n','') + '^', '^') + 1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but wanted to share this with any others that come across the post. I discovered an answer while browsing Microsoft's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference

I used a combination of **split()** and **length()** (only works with arrays). This way you don't need to nest a bunch of replace() functions. Use **split()** to divide the multiline field into an array of strings, separated by the specified character, in this case *\n* (i.e. new line). Then use **length()** to count the number of items in the array created by **split()**.

```
"txtContent": "=length(split([$Multiline], '\n'))"
```

**Disclaimer:** I used this with a plain text multiline field, and have not tested with rich text or enhanced text.